# Irrefutable pattern inside an action?

Tags: haskell

In my application several threads modify the same data. Whilst under "normal" circumstances there will always be a messages, I found out that with very large amounts of data it can happen that an other thread has been faster and deleted `messages` before `loopAction` runs.

```
transMit :: Socket -> POSIXTime -> String -> TPSQ -> TMap -> IO ()
transMit s time newmsgs q m = do
     loopAction <- atomically $ do
                       mT <- readTVar m
                       qT <- readTVar q
                       let mT' = Map.delete key mT
                       let qT' = PSQ.delete key qT
                       writeTVar q (PSQ.insert key time qT')
                       writeTVar m (Map.insert key [newmsgs] mT')
                       return (let Just messages = Map.lookup key mT in sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.35.84" 4711)
     loopAction
```

I tried here a case expressions such as

```
case (Map.lookup key MT) of
                           Nothing -> return ()
                           _ -> something w IO
```

but it does not work of course since the one returns () and the other branch returns IO (), etc.. What is my best take to resolve this?

Comment: By the way, `do {m <- mm; m} ≡ join mm`, so you could just write `join . atomically $ do ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the type error:

```
return $ case Map.lookup key mT of
              Nothing -> return ()
              Just messages -> sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.35.84" 4711
```

This way both branches yield a `IO ()`, resulting in a `STM (IO ())` overall.

But I'm not sure what's happening in terms of the values. `mT` surely can't be modified by a different thread...

Comment: @JFritsch Sorry, I added to my answer before I saw your comment. Is there still part of my answer I haven't explained well enough? Which part?